# replace regular expression via vimscript

Tags: regex, vim

I want to replace the following occurings:

```
@todo call customer
@todo-next do foo
@todo-wait customer will call me back
```

with `@done` when I am with the curser on the line. E.g:

```
@todo call customer
```

shall be then

```
@done call customer
```

I got it to replace `@todo` but for the other two (@todo-next, @todo-wait) I think my regex does not work properly...

Heres what I got, when I run it nothings happens on the lines...:

```
function! Tdone(  )
    let line=getline('.')
    "let newline = substitute(line, "@todo", "@done", "")
    let newline = substitute(line, "@todo.*? ", "@done", "")
    call setline('.', newline)
    :w
endfunction
```

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/20 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp syntax is wrong; Vim doesn't understand the Perlish `.*?`; that's `.\{-}` in Vim. See `:help perl-patterns`. (Additionally, since you're matching the trailing whitespace, you need to include that in the replacement, too, or use `\ze` to restrict the match.)

```
let newline = substitute(line, "@todo.\{-} ", "@done ", "")
```

I'd probably be more restrictive in your pattern, to avoid false matches (depends on the exact syntax of your markers, though, so this is just an example):

```
let newline = substitute(line, "@todo\%(-\w\+\)* ", "@done ", "")
```

Finally, there's no need for `getline()` / `setline()`; you can do that with `:substitute`, too. If you keep the function, this doesn't clobber the last search pattern. To clean up the history, `:call histdel('search', -1)`.

Comment: Why can't there be a standard way to do regex, would make situations like this moot if there was.

Comment: @user3536548: Why can't all people of the world speak the same language, would make communication much easier?!

Comment: Because the world is a very large place and language's evolved separate, where as coding languages evolved separately but in a shared communicative work space (the internet).  Your response only works if you don't take into account the fact that we have the means to communicate across the world. To be fair though the mass communication that we have now has only been available relatively recently.

Comment: @user3536548: Certain regexp features may be easy to implement in your engine (like when you have the mighty Perl interpreter), but difficult in a different one. Also, tasks in a text editor like Vim are different than using regexp in a programming language. Similarly, Eskimos need more words for "snow" than someone in the Sahara.

Comment: That's a much better response, as it pointed out things I didn't think of. I still think there should be a standard but if a standard would impede things then I guess it's better the way things are now.

Comment: @user3536548 I hate this, too, but have come to accept this. I often use `grep` / `sed`, Perl, and Vim, and all have small but crucial differences. Sigh.

Comment: @IngoKarkat it looks like using `:s` and `call histdel('search', -1)` does help with keeping the last search pattern however it does not seem to maintain the flags or last replacement correctly for commands like `:&&`. Is this a bug?

Comment: @PeterRincker: Indeed, you really need to resort to lower-level `setline()` to avoid all side effects. It would be great if Vim had a better solution, but I wouldn't call it a bug per se.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I know that in newer versions of Vim there is `:keeppatterns` however it too does not seem to maintain flags or replacements string (I am using 7.4 w/ patches 1-258). It would be nice if `:keepp` would do this or at the very least have some `v:` variables for both flags and last replacement so they can be restored later. Resorting to `getline`/`setline` is a bit crazy as not only is `:s` more convenient, but using `getline`/`setline` makes multiline substitutions much more work than needed.

Comment: Worked. I used as well you approach avoiding set/getline: `:s/@todo\%(-\w\+\)* /@done / `

Answer (score 0):

A regex to do that is:

```
:%s/\(@todo\)\( call.*\|-next.*\|-wait.*\)/@done\2/g
```